# what's is the base url which I have to use for virtocommerce?

Tags: azure, database-connection, e-commerce, virtocommerce

I try to use **virtocommerce** Ecommerce, I already install the manager on my computer,he asks 3 parameter to connect.

- login : admin
- password : store
- base URL : ??

If anyone can tell me what's the base URL that I can use it to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to demo site. Check for login parameters here: http://virtocommerce.com/try-now/online-demo